# return cleanup function from within finally block in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within a React function element I have a use Effect hood that has some callback based stuff going on. At the end of the callback chain, I need to return a function to cleanup on dismounting. How is that done.

I have something like this:

```
ReactFunctionElement=(..)=>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    asyncCall()
    .then(..)
    .cath(..)
    .finally(
      return ()=>{cleanup stuff}
     )
   },[some filters])
}
```

But the cleanup stuff never gets run. I don't know how, or if it is even possible, to lift that back out into the useEffect and return.

Comment: This seems wrong. What exactly do you do in the finally block?

Comment: I setup a bunch of webrtc stuff. [This line](https://github.com/Rehab-Robotics-Lab/LilFloSystem/blob/b8258243f5f369bea06c6bdd7d279b4cd454473b/flo_web/web_app/src/components/robotControl/Vids.tsx#L226) prints on connection [this line](https://github.com/Rehab-Robotics-Lab/LilFloSystem/blob/b8258243f5f369bea06c6bdd7d279b4cd454473b/flo_web/web_app/src/components/robotControl/Vids.tsx#L229) never prints, even when changing routes.

Comment: Why don't you define your connections outside of the finally block? and then just close them in the return function of useEffect? It can't work that way how you trying to do it. Thats not how useEffect works.

Comment: This scenario would be a nice use-case for implementing cancellable promises

Comment: @oemera I think I had been staring at the screen too long. That is the right solution. But regardless, it is good to know that the approach I was trying to take will not work. I couldn't figure out if there was a clever way to return things out of promises.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I had not run into the idea of cancellable promises. That is an interesting paradigm. I do think that could be used here, but I don't think it would make the code easy to read in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    // Closure variable
    const thingToCleanup = null;

    asyncCall()
        .then(thingToCleanup = thingFromAsync...)
        .catch(...);

    return () => { 
        // cleanup stuff using thingToCleanup
    });
} ,[some filters]) }
```

Your `useEffect` function has to return the clean up function, `.finally` returns a `Promise` which won't work but you also don't return that (JavaScript will implicitly return `undefined`). But you need access to some variables from the setup code in the cleanup so you store those in a closure to use later during clean up.

Comment: Yup, that does work. Now I'm off to figure out how to actually make WebRTC do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that return statement might fire before the conclusion of asyncCall.

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe an api call and in cleanup function you can unsubscribe it. here is an example:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    api.subscribe(userId);

    return () => api.unsubscribe(userId);
  }, [ userId ])
```